# Cocoa Window not remembering its position when reopening

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, nib

I started objective C last week so I'm just beginning to understand how the MVC design pattern works. Basically I downloaded this open source web app wrapper in cocoa:

https://github.com/maccman/macgap

and I want to alter it so it remembers its window position when I re-open it.

I've already tried opening up the nib and assigning a value to Autosave however this did not work. After researching the issue I discovered this is because the window controller automatically turns cascading on, so within WindowController.m I put

```
[[self.window windowController] setShouldCascadeWindows:NO];
[self.window setFrameAutosaveName:[self.window representedFilename]];
```

I tried putting this in windowDidLoad and the init methods however this did not work either and the window still did not remember its position.

Finally within AppDelegate I noticed that this is the code that actually creates the controller:

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification { 
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    self.windowController = [[WindowController alloc] initWithURL: kStartPage
                                                         andFrame:frame];
    [self.windowController showWindow: [NSApplication sharedApplication].delegate];
    self.windowController.contentView.webView.alphaValue = 1.0;
    self.windowController.contentView.alphaValue = 1.0;
    [self.windowController showWindow:self];
}
```

As I said I started objective-c last week (for iOS development) and from that I know that the NSMakeRect is what's determining the window position. Now, I also know from Java that I could do something like write the coordinates to a binary file when it moves, then read that file when I start up the program and just feed these values into NSMakeRect, however I don't think this is the most elegant solution.

Comment: Asking multiple questions under a single topic is not a cool thing to do.

Comment: @TBlue I've removed the second part of my question, sorry about that!